# Set point colors in CartoDB Torque

Tags: gis, data-visualization

Is there a way to set the colors of the data points in a CartoDB Torque visualization based on the values of another column in the table?  For example, if there is a magnitude column, is there a way to assign the color of a point to reflect its magnitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question on the CartoDB mailing list and heard back that such a feature is not provided by Torque.  However, they are currently working on ways to allow the user to customize the points.